# codeigniter active records aggregate not working

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-3

I'm using Codeigniter, what I want to do is a query that returns joined table (item_gallery) gallery_id is lowest value. while main query ordered by desc of items post_date

the below code group_by select random value of item_gallery gallery_id. but i want the lowest value of item_gallery gallery_id.

```
  public function shopItems($id) {

    $this->db->select("*,MIN(item_gallery.gallery_id)");
    $this->db->from('items');
    $this->db->join('item_gallery', 'items.id = item_gallery.item_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('items.user_id', $id);     
    $this->db->order_by('items.post_date', 'Desc');
    $this->db->group_by("item_gallery.item_id");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

database Structure

items table

```
|    id    |  slug  |  user_id  |  post_date |

|    12    |  test  |    111    |  12/5/2017 |
```

items Gallery

```
| gallery_id |  item_id  |     image     | 

|     121    |    12     |  profile.png  |   -- i want this record selected
|     122    |    12     |  gallery.png  |
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried MIN with a inner query inside the join condition?

```
    $this->db->select("*,MIN(item_gallery.gallery_id)");
    $this->db->from('items');
    $this->db->join('item_gallery', 'items.id = ( SELECT MIN(item_gallery.gallery_id) id FROM item_gallery WHERE items.id = item_gallery.item_id )', 'left');
    $this->db->where('items.user_id', $id);
    $this->db->order_by('items.post_date', 'Desc');
    $this->db->group_by("item_gallery.item_id");
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: not returns image.

Comment: Change $this->db->select("*,MIN(item_gallery.gallery_id)"); to $this->db->select("items.*,item_gallery.image");

Comment: not working after adding above code also, other issue comes with this code when there is 3 items only show one item with image not visible

Comment: Just tested the code.It's working fine for me (1st answer).

Comment: This will return only one row from item_gallery (lowest value of item_gallery gallery_id) along with the relevant item row. You need to correct the question if you want all the matching rows.

Comment: before your code -  http://imgur.com/a/EeYOA
after your code-  http://imgur.com/a/qCIj0

Comment: i want 1 min matched row from item_galley while all  the items from items table

Comment: Just add print_r($query) after the $query = $this->db->get(); and check for the result set.

Comment: try this,         $this->db->join('item_gallery', 'items.id = ( SELECT item_id FROM item_gallery WHERE items.id = item_gallery.item_id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1 ) ', 'left');

Comment: this above code displays repeated items.